# What is the speed of this spaceship? (Relativity)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, speed

There is a spaceship that located in Alpha Centauri (let's say spaceship A) and there is another spaceship located in Solar System (spaceship B).

If:

1. A is moving away from Alpha Centauri and Solar System
2. B is moving away the opposite direction
3. Distance of Alpha Centauri and Solar System is Fixed
4. Speed of A relative to Alpha Centauri $Va = \frac{C}{2}$
5. Speed of B relative to Solar System $Vb = \frac{C}{2}$
6. C = Light's Speed

Consider that all objects are standing in a straight line all the time

**What is the Speed of A Relative to B?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this site's [policy on homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/), I won't provide a complete answer.

You can use the [relativistic velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula)

$$V_f=\frac{v_1+v_2}{1+\frac{v_1v_2}{c^2}}$$

where $v_1$ and $v_2$ are the velocities of the spaceships as measured in the frame where both the solar system and Alpha Centauri are stationary. $V_f$ will be the velocity of each spaceship as measured from the other one.

Comment: This is not homework, I just Asked it this way for more clarification.

Comment: @RezaAzimi While it may not be actual homework, it still would be classified as such ("homework-*like*") as it asks for a specific computation. Anyway, you basically just need to plug in the values, so this should be fine.

Comment: Yep, I pluged in and the answer was 0.8C